# Is it safe to delete 'sites/modules.sav'?

Tags: 7, upgrading, backups

After the upgrade to the newest Drupal v7.31 I've found a new directory called sites/modules.sav with some subdirectories like

- entity
- entityreference
- securelogin
- securepages
- session443

What is the purpose of this directory?

Can I safely delete this entire directory 'modules.sav' after the successful upgrade?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not a default core behavior. How did you perform your upgrade?

Comment: According to https://www.drupal.org/taxonomy/term/34882

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as far as *Drupal* is concerned, it's safe to delete that folder. Whether it's needed for something outside of Drupal I obviously couldn't say.

Drupal didn't put it there, and unless you've got a very abnormal setup (which you'd undoubtedly know about already), it's not going to be looking in that folder for any files.

It's probably a remnant of whatever automated method you used to update Drupal; if you'd done the upgrade manually that folder wouldn't have appeared.

To be sure, take a full backup, remove the folder on a dev version of the site, and run the usual tests you would after a normal upgrade. If those all pass, you'll know 100%.

Comment: It was my very first Drupal upgrade (due to the security concerns). But maybe this directory was created by one of the various modules that I had to update too through the user interface (https://www.drupal.org/node/895232)?

Comment: @PeterCo I'm thinking it's something in the lines of backup software you have installed, or perhaps you have a Compaq.